# Woocommerce hook after customer login

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would need to do some actions after an already registered customer has logged in.
What would be the correct hook to use?

That is, what hook should I use in the add_filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is WooCommerce-specific. The general WordPress hook that fires when a user logs in is [`wp_login`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login)

To borrow the example from the Codex, you could do something like this:

```
function so_26675676_your_function($user_login, $user) {
    // your code
}
add_action('wp_login', 'so_26675676_your_function', 10, 2);
```

Comment: Just a small caveat: if the person logs in as "user123", has nothing in the cart when logging in, and there is a DB-stored session for "user123" (from previous logged-in activity), the "wp_login" hook is executed before that DB-stored session is restored. This means e.g. if you try to set any session variables through this hook, they will be lost after the page load following login...